# Timer function not firing on subsequent events

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have the following function that should trigger an HTTP Get call (getPollResults) every 3 seconds. The problem that I'm seeing is that only the initial event fires.

```
pollResults() {
  return timer(0, 3000)
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() =>  this.pollService.setPollResults()),
    tap(results=> {
      console.log(`updated results: `${results}`);
    })
  );
}

this.pollResults().subscribe()
```

If i remove the switchMap, it's working fine (I see a new console log every 3 seconds). So I believe it has to do with how switchMap works. Why would this be impeding on new events from the timer?

Comment: `switchMap` will unsubscribe from the current inner Observable returned from `this.pollService.setPollResults()` and subscribe to a new one every time `timer(0, 3000)` emits. So it looks like `setPollResults()` doesn't emit in the 3s time gap.

Comment: the service call is returning a value on the first event, even if i expand the timer to a longer interval, it won't trigger the next event.

Answer (score 1):

can you show us your code for the `setPollResults` function? Because the switchMap works as expected, see example below:

```js
const { of, timer } = rxjs; 
const { switchMap, tap, take } = rxjs.operators;


function pollResults() {
  return timer(0, 3000)
  .pipe(
    tap(timerval => console.log(`timer hit: ${timerval}`)),
    switchMap(() =>  of('foo')),
    tap(results=> {
      console.log(`updated results: ${results}`);
    }),
    take(5)
  );
}

pollResults().subscribe()
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`switchMap` will cancel the current request if it takes more that 3000ms,

you can use

`mergeMap` to send all requests or

`exhaustMap` to wait until the current request is done then sending a new one